# cisco 2500 series controller keeps dropping devices

Tags: cisco, wifi

I have a cisco 2504 controller with 3502 ap's. This is all configured and works a lot faster than our old system already except these seem to drop clients every 20-30mins or so for a few seconds.

What could cause this issue. I have removed all other access points and using 1 on its own so i know it can't be switching between ap's. What else could cause this and has anyone else had this issue?

Thanks

Comment: There's really not enough information in this question to help you.  How is the controller configured, and what have you tried so far for troubleshooting (aside from remove all the APs except one)?  And you did follow the guide, right? (http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/wireless/controller/7.0MR1/configuration/guide/cg_overview.html)

Comment: @user112570, could you post the log messages that pop up when the clients disassociate?

Comment: This is what were getting Client Deauthenticated: MACAddress:7c:11:be:89:32:ae Base Radio MAC:f4:7f:35:50:97:70 Slot: 0 User Name: unknown Ip Address: 192.168.23.219 Reason:Unspecified ReasonCode: 1

Comment: I have noticed this happens with every client every 30mins (1800 seconds) im not checking for a time out for this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. By default it was adding a timeout to each ssid of 1800 seconds. Just uncheck that and works fine.

Thanks everyone